# Find difference between date in table and midnight (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have table with data

Here is Model

```
public partial class Logging
{
    public string Imei { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CurDateTime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> GPSDateTime2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Latitude2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Longitude2 { get; set; }
    public string Speed { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Datatype { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public TimeSpan? FirstStartDifference { get { return CurDateTime - DateTime.Today; } }
    [NotMapped]
    public int coeff = 2;
}
```

I need to find data between  CurDateTime and midnight in minuutes

But `public TimeSpan? FirstStartDifference { get { return CurDateTime - DateTime.Today; } }` not right because `DateTime.Today` is today and I get difference in `-`.

On Controller I do it like this

```
   public JsonResult GetStops()
    {
        using (var ctx = new GoogleMapTutorialEntities())
        {
            var firstitem = ctx.Loggings.Where(x => x.Datatype == 1).AsEnumerable().Select(
                x => new
                {
                    lng = x.Longitude2,
                    lat = x.Latitude2,
                    difference = (int)(x.FirstStartDifference?.TotalMinutes ?? -1) * x.coeff
                }).FirstOrDefault();

            return Json(firstitem, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

How I can calculate difference correctly

Comment: Which attribute is the midnight? Is it CurDateTime? Also, you need data between two dates, why are you calculating this: FirstStartDifference ?

Comment: Updated question@alaa_sayegh

Comment: midnight, I mean 00:00@alaa_sayegh

Comment: time since midnight or time till midnight

Comment: Time since midnight@BugFinder

Comment: @S.E, are you sure that you need it like this: CurDateTime - DateTime.Today. Which is: 23.10.2017 00:00 - Now(23.10.2017 13:47)? Of course it will be always in minus. Is it not: now - midnight?

Comment: @S.E, then it should be now - midnight

Comment: In CurDateTime not now time. It can be another.

In my case it `10/18/2017 8:05:38 AM` for example. It's just table column name@alaa_sayegh

Comment: Oh yes. I edited post, sorry@alaa_sayegh

Comment: @S.E, see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you are subtracting your CurDateTime which is 10/18/2017 8:05:38 AM from DateTime.Today which is today's date at 00:00.
This will of course end up with minus value, because CurDateTime is smaller than today's date.

You need to subtract it from the midnight datetime of your CurDateTime.
Like this:

```
var midnight = new DateTime(CurDateTime.Year, CurDateTime.Month, CurDateTime.Day, 00, 00, 00);
var difference = CurDateTime - midnight;
var inMin = difference.TotalMinutes;
```

In your case:

```
 [NotMapped]
 public TimeSpan? FirstStartDifference
 {
    get
    {
      if(CurDateTime != null)
      {
        var midnight = new DateTime(CurDateTime.Year, CurDateTime.Month, CurDateTime.Day, 00, 00, 00);
        var difference = CurDateTime - midnight
        return difference;
      }
      return null;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hm. I have error in this part `CurDateTime.Year, CurDateTime.Month, CurDateTime.Day` .  'DateTime?' does not contain a definition for 'Year' and no extension method 'Year' accepting a first argument of type 'DateTime?' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: yes because your CurDateTime is null... Let us check for nullable value. If it is null, then no calculation can be done...

Comment: @S.E, check now please!

Answer (score 0):

you can get the difference of two time using

```
TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(endTime).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(startTime));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take properties Hour, Minute and Second and construct new DateTime from these values and it will be your needed difference. Or you can create new DateTime with 0 hour, 0 min and 0 sec and make substraction.

[Here is working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6pNT1e)

Answer (score 0):

You could do your calculation like you want or described by other answers but use `.Duration()` on result.
The method [`Duration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.timespan.duration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) will return the absolut result instead of a negative one.

Four your line of code:

```
public TimeSpan? FirstStartDifference 
{
    get 
    {
        if (!CurDateTime.HasValue)
        {
            return null
        }

        return (CurDateTime - DateTime.Today).Duration(); 
    } 
}
```

If you want the date value only from a `DateTime` object, just use the `Date` property instead of creating a new one.

e.g.

```
var myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
var myDate = myDateTime.Date;
```